# more button between two recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two recycler views in one screen and in between of them, there is one **more** button like this.

[image]

I want to update the height of recycler view of the upper one to **MATCH PARENT** with animation, So I had tried this.

```
binding.moreLl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt();
            anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = binding.fragmentWalletRv.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.height = val;
                    binding.fragmentWalletRv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }
            });
            anim.setDuration(500);
            anim.start();
        }
    });
```

But unfortunately i cant get the expected result. So please guide me how i can do that thing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have an animation when layout changes, no need to use a custom animation. 
Try adding default layout change animation by enabling

> android:animateLayoutChanges="true"

to the parent layout in xml.

On your more button click, only change the `LayoutParams` of the `Recyclerview`.

To change the speed of animation

```
LinearLayout layout = mContentView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
LayoutTransition lt = layout.getLayoutTransition(); 
lt.setDuration(2000);
```

Comment: The height is increasing but very fast,
i want little bit slow

Comment: LinearLayout layout = mContentView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
            LayoutTransition lt = layout.getLayoutTransition();
            lt.setDuration(500);
Try this to change the speed with the parent layout.

Comment: change the setDuration method value with something like 2000
lt.setDuration(2000); It's in milliseconds. So 2000 means 2 second to animate.

Comment: i set it to 5000 but still it is not slowing the animation

Comment: Are you changing the parent layout animation? It's the immediate parent of those two recyerlvews. Put animateLayoutChanges to immediate parent layout, get and setDuration for that only.

Comment: Added a new answer. Check it. It will surely work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SlideAnimation extends Animation {

    int mFromHeight;
    int mToHeight;
    View mView;

    public SlideAnimation(View view, int fromHeight, int toHeight) {
        this.mView = view;
        this.mFromHeight = fromHeight;
        this.mToHeight = toHeight;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation transformation) {
        int newHeight;

        if (mView.getHeight() != mToHeight) {
            newHeight = (int) (mFromHeight + ((mToHeight - mFromHeight) * interpolatedTime));
            mView.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
            mView.requestLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Use above animation like below

```
rv1 = findViewById(R.id.rv1);
Animation animation = new SlideAnimation(rv1, rv1.getHeight(), 500);
                animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                animation.setDuration(500);
                rv1.setAnimation(animation);
                rv1.startAnimation(animation);
```